# MySQL auto increment for certain groups in a DB table

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have the following mySQL table I have created and I am not sure how to auto increment the entry_id correctly. Ideally the auto-increment would work for each order_id. E.g If I have 3 entries for order id 1 then the these would have entry ID 1,2,3. Similarly if I have 3 entries for order id 2 then these would also have entry ID 1,2,3. Is this achievable?

```
/* Table `ims`.`OrderEntries` */
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ims`.`OrderEntries` (
    `ENTRY_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ORDER_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
    `ITEM_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
    `ITEM_NAME_AT_TIME_OF_ORDER` INT NOT NULL ,
    `ITEM_COST_AT_TIME_OF_ORDER` DECIMAL NOT NULL ,
    `ITEM_QUANTITY` INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_ID`, `ITEM_ID`)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to even bother implementing this, especially with the advent of MySQL 8+ which supports `ROW_NUMBER`.  To generate the series you describe above, you can simply use:

```sql
SELECT ENTRY_ID, ORDER_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID ORDER BY ENTRY_ID) SEQ
FROM OrderEntries
ORDER BY ORDER_ID, ENTRY_ID;
```

This would generate something looking like:

```
ENTRY_ID | ORDER_ID | SEQ
1        | 1        | 1
2        | 1        | 2
3        | 1        | 3
4        | 2        | 1
5        | 2        | 2
6        | 2        | 3
```

Comment: This won't work as I will need to run CRUD methods that will reference an entry using the order_id and the entry_id hence I need these numbers generated at the time of insertion.

Comment: Why do you think you need two sequences?  I doubt that you really need them.  Please explain your logic here.

Comment: I only need one sequence for the entry_id, I don't need a sequence for order ID as this is generated through a different table). My only issue is that when entries are added their id needs  to be mapped to an order ID. E.g. If my user wants to view the order entries related to a specific order_id the numbers won't be random and they will actually show as entry 1, entry 2, entry 3, etc.

If I were to just keep the AUTO_INCREMENT on the ENTRY_ID then this isn't mapped to the order_id.

The solution above works for view but not for delet. E.g. If a user wants to delete entry 2 for order id 1.

Comment: Well auto increment sequences will tend to be always increasing (some exceptions, but generally the rule).  So, you don't need `1, 2, 3` to figure out which order items were added first, you can simply check whatever numerical sequence is there.